# django rest framework can't get field name

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Struggling to get field name in serializer class:

```
from myapp.models import Image
class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ('image__image__url', )
```

my model:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True)
    image = FilerImageField()
```

In browser I get error: **Field name `image__image__url` is not valid for model `Image`.**

Although if I try in shell:

```
>>> from myapp.models import Image
>>> img = Image.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> img.image.url
'/media/filer_public/37/05/37054d47-2e23-4d05-80b5-a3183f10ea38/screenshot_from_2016-03-24_115543.png'
```

What might be the problem?

Comment: That would solve my problem, but why my current approach isn't working?

Comment: You shouldn't need `image` twice. It should just be `('image__url',)`

Comment: Tried this, still same error: Field name image__url is not valid for model Image.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need field lookup at all, just use field name, it will show `url` method in your response by default.

```
class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ('image', )
```

Comment: Well it's not showing. If I put `fields = ('image', )`, I get response: {"image":1}

Comment: @Mazas I'm don't know, what is `FilerImageField`, but if it inherit from standart `ImageField`, it should return `url` method by default, anyway you can call it manualy. Just declare this field in serializer, `image=serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='image.url')`